# Polynomials and Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A sixth degree polynomial $p(x)$ is divisible by its derived polynomial, and the derived polynomial is divisible by $(x-1)$. If $d$ is the coefficient of the highest degree of the polynomial $p(x)$, determine all roots of $p(x)=d$.

Comment: What have you tried?.  What does the first clause of the first sentence tell you?  The question is flawed because if you have a $p(x)$ that satisfies the first sentence, so will $kp(x)$.  $d$ will be multiplied by $k$ and the roots will change.  Please check.

Comment: I tried to conclude that 0 is root of p (x), but was unsuccessful. I also tried dividing p (x) by p '(x) and putting the rest as a multiple of the divisor
I edited the question to be clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(x)=(ax+b)P'(x)$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{P'(x)}{P(x)}=\frac{1}{ax+b}$$
Integrate both sides,
$$\Longrightarrow \log|P(x)|=\frac{1}{a}×(\log|ax+b|+\log|C|)$$
where the second term on RHS is constant of integration.
$$\Longrightarrow P(x)=(C(ax+b))^{\frac{1}{a}}$$
Now, degree of $P(x)$ is $6$, so $a=\frac{1}{6}$. Also, since, $x=1$ is a root of this polynomial, $a+b=0$, so $b=\frac{-1}{6}$. Now, the conditions are met for all values of $C$. Hence, the general solution is $P(x)=k(x-1)^6$, where $C=6k^\frac{1}{6}$. But the desired roots remain same for all values of $k$. Assume $k=1$. And the desired roots are $1+\omega$ where $\omega$ is a sixth root of unity.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Excellent!!!! ❤️

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence should tell you that $p(x)=k(x-1)^6$  I don't know if you have a theorem to that effect or have to show it.  If $p(x)$ has a linear factor to the first power it will have a root but its derivative will not at that point and so on.  Then $k=d$ and you are solving $(x-1)^6=1$

Comment: I didn't understand why 1 is root of multiplicity 6

Comment: Say $q(x)$ is a quadratic and we are told $q'(x)$ divides $q(x)$.  If $q(x)$ is not a constant times a square we can factor $q(x)=a(x-b)(x-c)$ with $b \neq c$.  Then $q'(x)=a[(x-b)+(x-c)]=a(2x-b-c)$ which does not divide $q(x)$, so $q(x)$ must be $a(x-b)^2$.  The same happens for sixth powers.

Comment: Great! Very grateful 